# FPS controlling game speed

Tags: java, timer, lwjgl, frame-rate

## background information

I've been in recent development of a game using LWJGL and I was curious as to how many frames per second I could get from running the game without using the Display.sync(60) function (Which limits fps to 60). Upon commenting out the code, I stumbled upon the game speed updating at 9000 some fps, which, in turn, made the game tick run 9 thousand times per second.

## question

How should I implement a game timer to prevent the fps creating issues with how fast the game actually runs? I am aware I need to separate the two timers, but how/which way is the most efficient of going about doing so (in java)?

Comment: See chapter 2 of _Killer Game Programming in Java_ from http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/

Comment: Pretty informative read. I appreciate the help. The diagram was similar to [what I was looking for](http://entropyinteractive.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/A-more-advanced-game-loop.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TheCodingUniverse offers a great tutorial here: http://thecodinguniverse.com/lwjgl-frame-rate-independent-movement/

However, the basic answer is that you move the frame by saving the last System.currentTime() and then compare it to this System.currentTime(). Then when moving it would be like `object.move(x * delta, y * delta);`

To quote from the above link,

```
// Under the class definition
private static long lastFrame;
private static long getTime() {
return (Sys.getTime() * 1000) / Sys.getTimerResolution();
}
private static double getDelta() {
long currentTime = getTime();
double delta = (double) currentTime - (double) lastFrame;
lastFrame = getTime();
return delta;
}
// In initialization code
lastFrame = getTime();
// In game loop
long delta = getDelta();
movement_x += dx * delta;
```

I hope that helps :).

Comment: In addition, you might also need to take the acceleration into account (e.g. acceleration per milisecond * delta instead of acceleration per frame).

Comment: @1337 I actually have no idea what you are talking about. Could you please explain?

Comment: Well, usually in game development objects have a velocity and because we want to have smooth movements we move those objects with velocity.x*delta and velocity.y*delta. But, usually, you want to accelerate those objects (when moving right or left, gravity, jumping, etc.) by a factor x. To avoid that the acceleration is FPS-dependent you should take that factor x as a factor per milisecond (so you can multiply it with delta) instaed of per frame, which seems to be a common approach.